# External Data Editing and Modification

Tags: sql-server, external-content-type, external-list, data

Can data in a SQL database be modified (new, delete, edit) through a SharePoint out-of-the-box feature or custom built feature?

Comment: what you mean by modifing? Do you mean adding the list items, documents or pages via customer features or you want directly update the data in Database's table?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an External Content Type and expose the SQL data to SharePoint.

Then create an External List through which you can perform the CRUD operations against the SQL database data.

**Creating an External Content Type based on SQL table**

1. Open a SharePoint site in SharePoint Designer
2. Click External Content Type
3. On the New External Content Type page, specify the Name, Display Name, Namespace etc.
4. Add a connection to the external system

   - Click here to discover external data sources and define operations.
   - Click the Add Connection button, select SQL Server in the External Data Source Type Selection dialog box and then click OK.
   - In the SQL Server Connection dialog box, specify the name of the SQL server.
   - Click Ok
5. Define the methods on the external system, Right click the table in question and say Create all Operations
6. Now you ECT is ready. You can create an External List to manage the data

For more information refer msdn article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee557243(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: So as far as creating a user dashboard to make changes to existing data (such as a contract) that's not possible?

Comment: How & Where the contract is stored?

Comment: It is possible @TomStewart to create, read, update, and delete from the SQL database which is what External Content Types gives you the ability to do. You just need to create the external content type which makes a connection to the SQL database.

Comment: It is stored in a SQL 2008 database